# How to convert object to string in java spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, converters

I want to search in spring data jpa by bedType. But, bedType is not string. Not **String bedType** but **BedType bedType(Object).** Here is my repository

```
    @Query("select a,b.bedType,b.roomCategory from RoomDetail a left outer join RoomMaster b on a.roomId = b.id where lower(b.bedType) like %:bedType%")
<Page>RoomDetail findByBedType(
        @Param("bedType") BedType bedType,
        Pageable paging);
```

FindRoomStatus.Java

```
public class FindRoomStatus {

private BedType bedType;

public BedType getBedType() {
    return bedType;
}

public void setBedType(BedType bedType) {
    this.bedType = bedType;
}
```

In my controller, I have got error

> String cannot be a converted to BedType

```
data = roomDetailRepository.findByBedType(findRoomStatus.getBedType().toString(), paging);
```

Here is BedType.Java

```
public class BedType implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "bed_type_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "bed_type_seq", sequenceName = "bed_type_id_bed_type_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
private int id;

@Column(name = "bed_type_name", length = 20)
private String bedTypeName;

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "status", length = 10)
private String status;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getBedTypeName() {
    return bedTypeName;
}

public void setBedTypeName(String bedTypeName) {
    this.bedTypeName = bedTypeName;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

List Room Status, in this list, i want to find by BedType

```
 {
            "id": 105,
            "roomId": 43,
            "floor": "1",
            "roomNumber": "001",
            "description": "Normal",
            "status": "Vacant Clean"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "bedTypeName": "King size"
        },
        {
            "id": 39,
            "categoryName": "President Suite"
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `LIKE` keyword in the query but you are accepting `BedType` object as a parameter in your query. You are sending `String` as an argument from your controller. This is the problem. `toString` method will give the string representation of an object.

What you can do is, change the parameter to `String` which accepts `bedTypeName` like:

```
@Query("select a,b.bedType,b.roomCategory from RoomDetail a left outer 
join RoomMaster b on a.roomId = b.id where lower(b.bedType.bedTypeName) like 
%:bedTypeName%")
<Page>RoomDetail findByBedType(
    @Param("bedTypeName") String bedTypeName,
    Pageable paging);
```

And from the controller,

```
data = roomDetailRepository.findByBedType(findRoomStatus.getBedType().getBedTypeName(), 
paging);
```

Comment: In my repository change to String bedType? not BedType bedType?

Comment: In your controller, change findRoomStatus.getBedType().toString() to findRoomStatus.getBedType();

Comment: Then how to i find by bed type? in the postman like this  { "bedType" : " " } String is " ", if not string what value of bedType : ?

Comment: Post your BedType class as well.

Comment: Please look again my post